# Calendar not loading in web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

This is the code which I used.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    function runAjax(selYearOptVal, selMonthOptVal) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "./calendar.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {
                // For Year
                var optYearValue;
                if ($('#selectYear option').length == 0) {
                    var select = $('#selectYear');
                    $(xml).find('year').each(function () {
                        optYearValue = $(this).attr('whichyear');
                        if (optYearValue == selYearOptVal) {
                            select.append("<option value='" + optYearValue + "' selected=\"selected\">" + optYearValue + "</option>");
                        } else {
                            select.append("<option value='" + optYearValue + "'>" + optYearValue + "</option>");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here, calendar.xml contains the list of holidays for each month. But calendar isn't loading, only holiday lists are loading. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your code at jsfiddle, show it.

Start debugging:

1. response - `console.log(xml);`
2. is true - `$('#selectYear option').length == 0`
3. is largest then 0 - `$(xml).find('year').length`

Comment: Actually that code is a part of whole code, I'll try whole code in JSFiddle and will post results....